# How to pick only latest records based on checkDate using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pyspark-pandas

I have a spark dataframe dataframe

```
vehicle_coalesce  vehicleNumber  productionNumber pin  checkDate
V123              V123           P123             null 27/08/2023 01:03
P123              null           P123             W123 27/08/2023 01:05
P123              null           P123             W123 27/08/2023 01:05
V234              V234           P234             null 27/08/2023 01:03
V234              V234           null             W234 27/08/2023 01:05
V234              V234           null             W234 27/08/2023 01:05
P456              null           P456             W456 27/08/2023 01:03
v456              V456           null             W456 27/08/2023 01:05
V456              V456           P456             W456 27/08/2023 01:05
```

I have to group by `vehicleNumber` or `productionNumber` or `pin` and partition by `vehicleNumber` or
`productionNumber` or `pin` and pick only latest records based on `checkDate`.

The required output is:

```
vehicle_coalesce  vehicleNumber  productionNumber pin  checkDate
P123              null           P123             W123 27/08/2023 01:05
P123              null           P123             W123 27/08/2023 01:05
V234              V234           null             W234 27/08/2023 01:05
V234              V234           null             W234 27/08/2023 01:05
v456              V456           null             W456 27/08/2023 01:05
V456              V456           P456             W456 27/08/2023 01:05
```

Here, since `V123` vehicle has same `productionNumber` it is grouped by it and picked latest records, and for `V234` since it has same `vehicleNumber` it is grouped by it and picked latest records and for `V456` since it has same `pin` it is grouped by it and picked latest records

How to get it using pyspark?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to group by 'vehicleNumber', 'productionNumber' **OR** 'pin', I would use three distinct windows ordered by `checkDate`. For each window, one for each column, I would keep null values of the column of interest and the rows with the last `checkDate`.

It could be written as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

result = df
for column in ['vehicleNumber', 'productionNumber', 'pin']:
    window = Window.partitionBy(column).orderBy(F.col("checkDate").desc())
    result = result\
        .withColumn("r", F.rank().over(window))\
        .where(F.col(column).isNull() | (F.col("r") == 1))\
        .drop("r")

result.show()
```

```
+----------------+-------------+----------------+----+----------------+
|vehicle_coalesce|vehicleNumber|productionNumber| pin|       checkDate|
+----------------+-------------+----------------+----+----------------+
|            P123|         null|            P123|W123|27/08/2023 01:05|
|            P123|         null|            P123|W123|27/08/2023 01:05|
|            V234|         V234|            null|W234|27/08/2023 01:05|
|            V234|         V234|            null|W234|27/08/2023 01:05|
|            v456|         V456|            null|W456|27/08/2023 01:05|
|            V456|         V456|            P456|W456|27/08/2023 01:05|
+----------------+-------------+----------------+----+----------------+
```